# Solving 1D Advection Equation Using Midpoint-Rule and Finite-Differences

Tags: ode, runge-kutta, advection

I want to solve the advection equation ($v_0 \in \mathbb R$)
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + v_0 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0
$$

using 2nd order Runge Kutta like the midpoint rule for the time integration and an upwind (backwards finite differences) for the spatial derivation.

Here is a general Runge-Kutta implementation in python

```
def rk2a( f, x0, t ):
    n = len( t )
    x = np.array( [ x0 ] * n )
    for i in range( n - 1 ):
        h = t[i+1] - t[i]
        k1 = h * f( x[i], t[i] ) / 2.0
        x[i+1] = x[i] + h * f( x[i] + k1, t[i] + h / 2.0 )

    return x
```

And that makes sense and if I'd have to solve something like $y'=f=x$ I'd know how to pass $f$ but I'm confused because now we have $f=-v_0\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

Since I want to use an upwind scheme for the spatial derivative, we have

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{i-1/2} = \frac{q^{n}_i - q^{n}_{i-1}}{x_i - x_{i-1}}
$$

whereas $n$ denotes the $n$-th timestep and $i$ denotes the $i$-th grid point.

Now to implement that, I'd have to write down `f( x[i], t[i] )` and `f( x[i] + k1, t[i] + h / 2.0 )` resp. provide a general `f`.

Now while I think I can write down `f( x[i], t[i] )`, I have no idea how I'd write down `f( x[i] + k1, t[i] + h / 2.0 )`.

So the question is: How do I use a upwind scheme in the midpoint rule?

Edit: I assume equispaced grid.

Comment: I think you would find it very helpful to read a good introductory book on numerical methods.  For instance,  chapter 10 of [LeVeque's finite difference book](https://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/fdmbook/) will answer your question and give you a lot of other important information about what you're doing.

Comment: What you have written here is a bit confusing because you are writing $f$ to mean two different things (the solution of the PDE and the RHS of the ODE).

Comment: Ah, that's an issue stemming from rewriting the topic. I know that there's a difference between the f's.